# How to solve Warning with /imu_frame using robot_localization package?

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using robot_localization package on ROS Kinetic to fuse imu data with wheel encoder odometry and generate a odometry/filtered message to navigate using AMCL for localization. My robot uses a raspberry pi 3 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 and Arduino boards. It uses a Neato XV-11 Lidar for the laser scans.
My launch works but the terminal does not stop to print this Warning message:

```
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

Also, in Rviz the topic /odometry/filtered got blinking errors at a rate of 4 Hz.

The Rviz error :

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [odom]: No transform to fixed frame [map]. TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1516667536.039499044 but the latest data is at time 1516667536.027499399, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]]
```

When it has no error:

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
Transform OK
```

**What is the error in my application? Is there a solution to stop this warning?**

Thank you! =)

**I tried to upload images but I dont have points enough in ros answers.**

My tf tree is:

**Map** -----/amcl (avg rate:4.05)-----> **odom**  ----- /ekf_localization_node_odom2base (avg rate 49.5) ---> **base_link**

**base_link** ------- /tf_neato (avg rate:96.7) ------ > **laser**

**base_link** -------- /tf_imu (avg rate: 97.0) ---------> **imu_frame**

Here is the ekf_localization.yaml config file:

```
#2nd config for the 2nd node to make tf odom to base_link
#It is almost identical, just world_frame: odom. 

#Configuration for robot odometry EKF
#
frequency: 50

two_d_mode: true

publish_tf: true

base_link_frame: base_link
odom_frame: odom
map_frame: map
world_frame: odom

#meaning_matrix_config: [   X,           Y,      Z,
#                       roll,       pitch,    yaw,
#                       X/dt,        Y/dt,    Z/dt,
#                       roll/dt, pitch/dt,  yaw/dt,
#                       X/dt2,      Z/dt2,   Z/dt2]

odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false

imu0: /imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, true,
               true, false, false]
imu0_differential: false
```

Here is the terminal of my_file.launch:

```
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/a276a068-ffcc-11e7-a672-b827ebd25c92/roslaunch-pi-desktop-730.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.42.0.1:45873/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /amcl/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /amcl/first_map_only: False
 * /amcl/global_frame_id: map
 * /amcl/gui_publish_rate: 10.0
 * /amcl/kld_err: 0.01
 * /amcl/kld_z: 0.99
 * /amcl/laser_lambda_short: 0.1
 * /amcl/laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
 * /amcl/laser_max_beams: 100
 * /amcl/laser_max_range: -1
 * /amcl/laser_min_range: -1
 * /amcl/laser_model_type: likelihood_field
 * /amcl/laser_sigma_hit: 0.1
 * /amcl/laser_z_hit: 0.85
 * /amcl/laser_z_max: 0.0
 * /amcl/laser_z_rand: 0.15
 * /amcl/laser_z_short: 0.0
 * /amcl/max_particles: 3000
 * /amcl/min_particles: 500
 * /amcl/odom_alpha1: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha2: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha3: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha4: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha5: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /amcl/odom_model_type: diff
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
 * /amcl/resample_interval: 1
 * /amcl/save_pose_rate: 0.5
 * /amcl/transform_tolerance: 0.2
 * /amcl/update_min_a: 0.5
 * /amcl/update_min_d: 0.2
 * /amcl/use_map_topic: True
 * /clear_costmaps/delay_seconds: 15
 * /comandar_joy_node/scale_angular: 0.8
 * /comandar_joy_node/scale_linear: 0.25
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/base_link_frame: base_link
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/frequency: 50
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/imu0: /imu
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/imu0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/imu0_differential: False
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/map_frame: map
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/odom0: /odom
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/odom0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/odom0_differential: False
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/odom_frame: odom
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/publish_tf: True
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/two_d_mode: True
 * /ekf_localization_node_odom2base/world_frame: odom
 * /joy_node/autorepeat_rate: 5.0
 * /laser_filter/scan_filter_chain: [{'type': 'LaserS...
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 1.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_y: 0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/controller_frequency: 5
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_vel: -0.18
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead: 1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 0.4
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 0.25
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.4
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_theta: -0.4
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x: 0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/planner_frequency: 0.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity: 0.05
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 1.5
 * /move_base/controller_frequency: 6.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/allow_unknown: False
 * /move_base/global_costmap/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[0.31, 0.25], [-...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: /map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius: 1.35
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/observation_persistence: 0.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: laser
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: /scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 4
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/allow_unknown: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[0.31, 0.25], [-...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: /map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 4.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius: 1.35
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/observation_persistence: 0.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: laser
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: /scan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 2.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 0.025
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 4
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 4.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    clear_costmaps (simple_navigation_goals/clear_costmaps)
    comandar_joy_node (comandar_joy/comandar_joy_node)
    ekf_localization_node_odom2base (robot_localization/ekf_localization_node)
    encoder_odom_node (encoder_odom/encoder_odom_node)
    global_loc (rosservice/rosservice)
    joy_node (joy/joy_node)
    laser_filter (laser_filters/scan_to_scan_filter_chain)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    mux_cmd_vel (topic_tools/mux)
    neato_laser_publisher (xv_11_laser_driver/neato_laser_publisher)
    rosserial_enc_node (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    rosserial_imu_node (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    tf_imu (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    tf_neato (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [743]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311

setting /run_id to a276a068-ffcc-11e7-a672-b827ebd25c92
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [763]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rosserial_enc_node-2]: started with pid [790]
process[rosserial_imu_node-3]: started with pid [791]
process[encoder_odom_node-4]: started with pid [792]
process[ekf_localization_node_odom2base-5]: started with pid [793]
process[tf_neato-6]: started with pid [802]
process[tf_imu-7]: started with pid [822]
process[neato_laser_publisher-8]: started with pid [839]
process[laser_filter-9]: started with pid [858]
process[joy_node-10]: started with pid [871]
process[comandar_joy_node-11]: started with pid [882]
process[map_server-12]: started with pid [895]
process[amcl-13]: started with pid [906]
process[move_base-14]: started with pid [916]
process[mux_cmd_vel-15]: started with pid [938]
process[clear_costmaps-16]: started with pid [954]
process[global_loc-17]: started with pid [968]
[ INFO] [1516664012.012990431]: Opened joystick: /dev/input/js0. deadzone_: 0.050000.
[ INFO] [1516664012.825227462]: advertising
[INFO] [1516664014.784336]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1516664014.822275]: ROS Serial Python Node
[ INFO] [1516664014.836192252]: Subscribed to map topic.
[INFO] [1516664014.909306]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM1 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [1516664014.939798]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
ERROR: Service [/move_base/clear_costmaps] is not available.
[ INFO] [1516664016.056148242]: Received a 2000 X 2000 map @ 0.025 m/pix

[INFO] [1516664017.093658]: Note: publish buffer size is 100 bytes
[INFO] [1516664017.098933]: Setup publisher on /enc_Int32 [std_msgs/Int32MultiArray]
[INFO] [1516664017.199318]: Note: subscribe buffer size is 100 bytes
[INFO] [1516664017.203235]: Setup subscriber on cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]
[INFO] [1516664017.573205]: Note: publish buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1516664017.580501]: Setup publisher on imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[ INFO] [1516664017.733794439]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1516664019.463331053]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.101917 timeout was 0.1.
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1516664024.464761415]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.101563 timeout was 0.1.
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ INFO] [1516664026.999812925]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[ INFO] [1516664027.003602717]: Initializing with uniform distribution
[ INFO] [1516664027.088936883]: Global initialisation done!
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
[global_loc-17] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pi/.ros/log/a276a068-ffcc-11e7-a672-b827ebd25c92/global_loc-17*.log
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: Invalid argument "/imu_frame" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.16/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280755/how-to-solve-warning-with-/imu_frame-using-robot_localization-package?/) by [VitorHirozawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33360/vitorhirozawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm answering your main question now:

`tf2` expects all Frames without a leading `/`. So you need to remove this leading `/` in your IMU node. Either via config, if possible, or in the source code.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3